# Groovy map creation, use value assigned to previous key

Tags: dictionary, groovy

Is there a way to use the values assigned to the previous key in map, for eg:

```
def x = [
        a: someList.sum(),
        b: anotherList.sum(),
        c: someList.sum() / anotherList.sum()
]
```

I want the value of 'c' to be a/b, so is there a shortcut so that I don't have to recompute the sums while computing  'c'

Comment: `def a = 1; def x = [a: a, b: a + 1]`?

Comment: that was obvious but not what I was looking for

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? I can't think of a reason apart from theoretical.

Comment: I second Tim. `def x = [a: 1]; x.b = x.a + 1` can be used.

Comment: ok I have rephrased the question based on comments

Comment: The two workarounds can still be applied. I'm no groovy expert, but I doubt what you want, in the way you want, is possible.

Comment: Agreed the two arounds can be used, but I was looking for more like a concise code style, if one exists for this scenario

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use previously-added key/values to compute new key/values, you must be able to control the order in which the keys/values are added. I know that's obvious, but what may not be obvious is that Groovy `Map` declarations do not take order into account. For example, if you write this...

```
def x = [
        a: 8,
        b: 2,
        c: a / b
]
```

..., when evaluating the expression for the value of key `c`, Groovy will attempt to access a variable or property named `a`, which will fail because the variable/property does not exist. However, you can take advantage of that property lookup and do this:

```
def x = [:].with {
    a = 8
    b = 2
    c = a / b

    delegate
}
```

You start by creating an empty `Map`. Then, use `with(Closure)` to execute `putAt()` and `get()` against the `Map`. The example above is the equivalent to...

```
def x = [:].with {
    putAt('a', 8)
    putAt('b', 2)
    putAt('c', get('a') / get('b'))

    delegate
}
```

Finally, return the `Map` itself so that it's assigned to `x`.

Comment: If you wanted to use an approach like that, I think it could be simplified with something like https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/4182689de487968b9f7f57e8f3ba08aa

Comment: You can return `it` instead of `delegate`